# Machine Learning: NBA data to find MVP of season

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, data-mining, accord.net

I want to use NBA data to find the MVP for a particular season. I was looking at a couple of algorithms like Neural Networks, AdaBoost, Random Forest, and Decision Trees. I really want to use AdaBoost but the problem with AdaBoost is that it seems like I can only use one feature if I'm using a decision stump as my weak learner. I want to use all the data like playing time, points, and standing/record to see if it can classify the MVP for that season. I want to know if there're any machine learning algorithms I can use for this project or let me know if I can use these algorithms for what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use machine learning you are going to need past data, or some way of defining the MVP. Once you have data, you can make a basic neural network. However, you would need a lot of data to train a machine learning neural network, and there are simply not enough NBA seasons to do so. Using decision trees and/or other classical algorithms maybe a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you can use regression to predict number of votes on different season, the player with highest predictive value is MVP, here is the [data source](http://www.basketball-reference.com/awards/mvp.html) for your reference.